# How could I send response using json instead of jade?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

//This is my index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Movie Database' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

//This is my index.jade file

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Finally, I want to do the same thing using json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `res.send(/*your json*/);`. Like:

```
res.send({ title: '...' });
```

See the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

Comment: and how can I do this when I want to retrieve data from mongo database and send it using json.

Comment: that would be a separate topic. I suggest you read any tutorial on mongodb & nodejs. it should be fairly easy but very long to explain here.